# disable a KBUILD_CFLAGS option when making a driver

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kbuild

I'm attempting to compile this UART -> USB [driver](https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers) from silicon labs. It has only been tested on Ubuntu version `18.04 (Bionic)` and my machine is running on `21.10 (Impish)`. Apparently one of the differences is that the newest version enables strict pointer conversion checking when building kernel modules:

**/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/Makefile**

```
# enforce correct pointer usage
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += $(call cc-option,-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to disable that particular flag as it prevents me from compiling the driver. I get the error:

```
.../vcp_driver_source/Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:290:35: error: initialization of ‘void (*)(struct usb_serial_port *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct usb_serial_port *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  290 |         .port_remove            = cp210x_port_remove,
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.../vcp_driver_source/Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.c:290:35: note: (near initialization for ‘cp210x_device.port_remove’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:277: .../vcp_driver_source/Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source/cp210x.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1874: .../vcp_driver_source/Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.23-76051523-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2
```

The Makefile is very simple and I can change it as needed

**Makefile**

```
obj-m = cp210x.o
KDIR = /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
SRCDIR = $(PWD)
# try this instead if you don't have PWD defined
# SRCDIR = $(shell dirname $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(SRCDIR) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(SRCDIR) clean
```

Comment: It would be better to fix the problem in the driver source code rather than mess with the compiler flags.

Comment: You could just install the `linux-modules-extra` package and then you would not need to build this module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the following to the top of the makefile fixed the problem

```
ccflags-y := -Wno-error=incompatible-pointer-types
```

From the [linux kernel documentation](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) I was able to find

> --- 3.7 Compilation flags
>
> ccflags-y, asflags-y and ldflags-y
> These three flags apply only to the kbuild makefile in which they
> are assigned. They are used for all the normal cc, as and ld
> invocations happening during a recursive build.
> Note: Flags with the same behaviour were previously named:
> EXTRA_CFLAGS, EXTRA_AFLAGS and EXTRA_LDFLAGS.
> They are still supported but their usage is deprecated.
>
> ccflags-y specifies options for compiling with $(CC).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> ccflags-y            := -Os -D_LINUX -DBUILDING_ACPICA
> ccflags-$(CONFIG_ACPI_DEBUG) += -DACPI_DEBUG_OUTPUT
> ```
>
> This variable is necessary because the top Makefile owns the
> variable $(KBUILD_CFLAGS) and uses it for compilation flags for the
> entire tree.

After that is was just a matter of finding the correct gcc flag. Thankfully gcc provides a way to unset the `-Werror` flag with `-Wno-error`. Setting that overrides the default behavior and allows the compilation to work without issue.